# How can I use software BRIDE in ROS FUERTE?

Tags: ros, python, rosws, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to use BRIDE in ROS FUERTE as sain in the page  http://wiki.ros.org/bride/Tutorials/Creating-nodes-with-BRIDE-and-cplusplus but i cannot create a workspace in catkin because the command catkin_init_workspace generates this error:

```
catkin_init_workspace: command not found
```

Then I tried to create the workspace with rosbuild as said in
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment
but I had another problem when i use the command:

```
rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
```

an error is displayed:

```
ImportError: No module named vcs_abstraction
```

and when i tried to install rosinstall: `sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall`

Another error is displayed:

```
Errors where encountered while processing:
python-catkin-pkg
python-rospkg
python-rosdistro
python-rosdep
python-rosinstall
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199110/how-can-i-use-software-bride-in-ros-fuerte?/) by [jav_greepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21055/jav_greepo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-12-08**:
Yes, you should use rosbuild in ROS Fuerte. Maybe you can reference the Ros answer:
[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/69949/problems-with-rosrun-rosws-and-others/)

**Comment by [jav_greepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21055/jav_greepo/) on 2014-12-08**:
I followed the link but it doesnt works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte does not have `catkin`, that is why the `catkin_init_workspace` command does not work.

You will either have to update to a newer version of ROS like Hydro or Indigo or you will have to get a `rosbuild` version of BRIDE if it is available. I'm not sure if there are tutorials for using BRIDE with rosbuild, perhaps someone else can answer that.

I would recommend you update your ROS version though because Fuerte has been unsupported for quite some time now. I would recommend using Indigo, as it will be supported for another 4+ years.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0